# MuleContext object in Connector Code

Tags: mule

I am trying to get MuleContext object in my Connector code. I am trying to create a connector in Mule. Below are my questions:

1. Can I pass MuleContext object from the mule flow which is calling the Connector I have created.
2. Can I get the MuleContext object inside the Connector class only. Once I place this connector in my flow it would take the correct context automatically?

Comment: There's one `MuleContext` instance per Mule application, it's not Flow specific in any way.

Comment: Thanks David. I have the same query about MuleEventContext object. How can I find this in my connector code.

Comment: You can easily receive the current `MuleEvent` in your connector's methods. `MuleEventContext` is another story though, what do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

MuleContext will be automatically passed to your connector by Mule. Just make your connector implement MuleContextAware interface.
The other way is to try to inject it like

```
 @Inject
 private MuleContext muleContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your inputs.

We have tried using RequestContext.getEventContext().getMessage().getPaylod().toString();

This is to retrieve the payload in my mule flow however this piece of code is in connector class.